# При отправке данных на сервер ASP.NET Web api ошибка 403

Tags: java, android-studio, asp.net-web-api

Я делаю авторизацию Android клиента с помощью ASP.NET Web API веб-сервера. Ввожу логин, нажимаю ввод, получаю ответ пользователь найден. Но это только через андроид эмулятор. Когда я пытаюсь на реальном устройстве, то ошибка 403. Порт на роутере открыт и на компьютере тоже. Телефон и компьютер в той же сети. Страничка которая есть на этом сервере открывается в телефоне если в браузере вбить ип компьютера и порт (192.168.0.101:7899). Вот такой запрос на сервер:

```
@GET("/login")
void findLogin(@Query("login") String login, Callback<Users> callback);
```

Вот код подключения:

```
public class RestClient {
   private UploadService  uploadService;
     private String URL ="http://192.168.0.101:7899/api/";       
    public RestClient(){
            Gson localGson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            this.uploadService = ((UploadService)new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(URL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(localGson))
                    .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                        public void intercept(RequestFacade requestFacade) {
                            if (URL.contains("192.168.0.101")) {                             
                                requestFacade.addHeader("Host", localhost");
                            }
                        }
                    })
            .build().create(UploadService.class));    
    }
```

Код WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Re‌ferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            // Конфигурация и службы веб-API
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
            // Маршруты веб-API
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Как решить проблему с ошибкой 403?

Comment: HTTP статус 403 обычно говорит о том, что сервер отверг запрос, исходя из политики безопасности. Чтобы разобраться необходимо либо видеть логи сервера, либо знать точный контракт авторизации и аутентификации при запросах к этому серверу.

Comment: @Nofate Помоги решить ошибку 403, привел код.